# how to prevent parameter from url?

Tags: php

i have this example website

```
site.com/path/file.php
```

i want to prevent user from adding `file.php?id=` or any thing after `file.php`

what should i do ? i want make this url requested as it is and prevent any additional parameters

Things i think to do is parsing the url but is this will be helpful in playing with parameters ?

i mean what if parser reads `file.php?id` and the page requested `file.php?page=`

Comment: you can't prevent it, but you can ignore it or redirect invalid requests.

Comment: If you don't use GET params it doesn't really matter if somone adds them. I'm sure very very few will try to just randomly add params to a url.

Comment: You could do a redirect in `.htaccess`.

Comment: @chris85 isn't this can be bypassed

Comment: @mistermartin interesting example ?

Comment: @JimL its highly needed in my case i am trying to limit that url access and i want to kill that php if its contain parameter ignore is really bad

Comment: Not if written right. Users could still send POST requests though..

Comment: @chris85 interesting showing right example would be helpful as well

Comment: You could do something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523311/removing-get-parameter-in-htaccess, but just check that the query string is not empty, not for specific value.

Comment: reading that this "is needed" just makes me think you are doing something else wrong. like having register globals on and not wanting people to inject url parameters or using `$_REQUEST` for your post parameters. It shouldn't matter what get parameters are passed and I would be surprised if you could come up with a good reason why. You just use the ones you need and ignore the rest.

Comment: @chris85 will not help either still the same logic is up what if users change View=

Comment: You only will get the values in the parameters if you write your code to do so...

Comment: @JonathanKuhn i am not doing any thing wrong ! no even code added , this needed for protection purpose on access single file . this file not even work as registration form or any thing else its just a downloader File

Comment: Don't put `view`, check for anything (`!^$`).

Comment: Then why do the get parameters matter if it is "just a downloader"? Removing them or requiring zero parameters wouldn't add any protection. Absolutely zero.

Comment: a file protection ? a limitation of access in case of http request attack if file size large ? many many things explain why

Comment: but how would get parameters allow someone to request a large file over and over when removing them wouldn't? Unless you are logging the requested url, to track downloads and different query strings are counted as different urls. In that case, you are doing it wrong. You shouldn't track downloads by url like that, but by a nonce token or just the file accessed, either one tied to a username.

Comment: lol . here is the trick that file already recorded the path that requested and recording the connection so if this file requested within  Time exceeded the old request will not be downloaded , using some htacc to redirect the file itself to that php file and make the header of downloading . thats basically thinking  playing with parmeter will allow this file to requested as different path each Time . its not my issue if you dont get the whole concept of protection my question was about the parmeter you drag the topic to infinity place

Comment: marked as duplicated sense @chris85 gives me the simple equation . Thanks Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch any arguments, in the URL or posted, with:

```
if (count($_GET)+count($_POST) > 0)
{
  <execute some error code>
  die('Ah, you cannot do that!');
}
```

Comment: Thats help Too Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One method you could try is not using the same page to process functions. Use AJAX requests and restrict your designated Post PHP page like **"/include/processmyform.php"** or something to only allow AJAX Requests/Only allow AJAX requests from your web server.

```
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&  strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
if(!IS_AJAX) {
    #You can use this condition to ignore or block their request.
    die('That method is not allowed!');
} else {
    #If they did post AJAX, make sure it's a legitimate request from your server.
    $pos = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],getenv('HTTP_HOST'));
    if($pos===false) {
        die('That method is not allowed!');
    } else {
        #All good - Cooking with hot grease!
        $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);
        $somevar = htmlspecialchars($_POST['someparam']);
    }
}
```