# How can I remove a single get parameter and change it to just a slask in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So my url is like this: `http://localhost/gender/?name=robert`

What I wanted to do is to remove the name value pair and make it just like `http://localhost/gender/robert`

I googled and got this one `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523311/removing-get-parameter-in-htaccess` but it seems to complicated for me.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?name=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^robert$ gender/?name=robert&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

If you want this to work for all pages i.e. /any-page gets served as index.php?page=any-page then use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ gender/?name=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

How do these rules work?

A `RewriteRule` has the following syntax

```
RewriteRule [Pattern] [Substitution] [Flags]
```

The Pattern can use a regular expression and is matched against the part of the URL after the hostname and port (with the `.htaccess` placed in the root dir), but before any query string.